# In a CASE statement, can you store WHEN subquery result for use in the THEN output?

Tags: oracle, plsql, reporting

I have a report outputting the results of a query which was designed to provide links to a webpage:

```
SELECT 
a, 
b, 
c, 
'string' || 
(SELECT sso_code 
       FROM men_sso 
       WHERE sso_parm LIKE '%URL_LINK~' || ipp_code || '%' 
       ORDER BY sso_cred, sso_cret 
       FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY
) AS URL
FROM men_ipp
```

This works well, but I was asked to amend it so that if the records needed to generate the URL were missing (ie. sso_code can't be retrieved), it outputs a warning message instead of the subquery output.

Since there's always going to be a string of a set length (6 characters in this example), my solution was to create a CASE statement which is evaluating the length of the subquery output, and if the answer is greater than 6 characters it returns subquery result itself, otherwise it returns a warning message to the user.  This looks like:

```
SELECT 
a, 
b, 
c, 
CASE 
  WHEN 
    LENGTH('string' || 
       (SELECT sso_code 
       FROM men_sso 
       WHERE sso_parm LIKE '%IPP_URL_LINK~' || (ipp_code) || '%' 
       ORDER BY sso_cred, sso_cret 
       FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY)  
     ) > 6
  THEN 
    ('string' || 
       (SELECT sso_code 
       FROM men_sso 
       WHERE sso_parm LIKE '%IPP_URL_LINK~' || (ipp_code) || '%' 
       ORDER BY sso_cred, sso_cret 
       FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY)
  ELSE 'warning message'
END AS URL
FROM men_ipp
```

The statment works fine, however the processing time is nearly doubled because it's having to process the subquery twice.  **I want to know if there's any way to store the result of the subquery in the WHEN, so it doesn't need to be run a second time in the THEN?  eg. as a temporary variable or similar?**

I've tried to declare a variable like this:

```
DECLARE URLLINK NVARCHAR(124);
SET URLLINK = 'string' || 
(SELECT sso_code 
       FROM men_sso 
       WHERE sso_parm LIKE '%URL_LINK~' || ipp_code || '%' 
       ORDER BY sso_cred, sso_cret 
       FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY
)
```

However this causes the query to error saying the it `Encountered the symbol "https://evision.dev.uwl.tribalsits.com/urd/sits.urd/run/siw_file_load.sso?" when expecting one of the following:   := . ( @ % ; not null range default character`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `NULLIF` to make the result null if it is "string" (i.e., you appended nothing to it from your subquery).  Then use `NVL` to convert to the warning message.  Something like this:

```
SELECT 
a, 
b, 
c, 
nvl(nullif(
'string' || 
       (SELECT sso_code 
       FROM men_sso 
       WHERE sso_parm LIKE '%IPP_URL_LINK~' || (ipp_code) || '%' 
       ORDER BY sso_cred, sso_cret 
       FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY),'string'),'warning message')
FROM men_ipp
```

Comment: This only works because of the particulars of your question.  The answer by @Littlefoot is more generally correct re: how to reuse values in SQL.

Comment: Nonetheless, NULLIF does the job as well (without running the same code twice).

Comment: Thanks very much, this worked so I've marked it as solved - although as you say Littlefoot's solution seem like the more re-useable option for other queries (if I can ever get it working properly!)

Answer (score 1):

Use a CTE.

```
with temp as
  (SELECT sso_code
       FROM men_sso 
       WHERE sso_parm LIKE '%IPP_URL_LINK~' || (ipp_code) || '%' 
       ORDER BY sso_cred, sso_cret 
       FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY
  )
select a, b, c,
  case when sso_code is null then 'warning message'
       else 'string' || sso_code
  end as url
from men_ipp full outer join temp on 1 = 1;
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why `FULL OUTER JOIN temp ON 1=1` instead of `CROSS JOIN temp`?

Comment: @Matthew: because - if there's no row in MEN_SSO table, there'll be nothing returned by a CTE and final result will be just the same - no rows. With full outer join, you'd get the "warning message".

Comment: Thanks for the help - I've tried your solution, but it errors and gives me `Server: ORA-24374: define not done before fetch or execute and fetch`

Comment: I don't think that this is related to query itself, but "something else". Which tool do you use? Are there multi-line **comments** in your code (if so, try to remove them).

Comment: Unfortunately the tool I'm using is contained within another system (a student records system, itself built on uniface), so it's not really a standard oracle tool that I can get any info on / support for.  There are no comments in the query, but you're probably right that it's an issue with how the query is being parsed somehow.  Thanks very much for your response anyway, if I can ever get it working properly it should be a very useful technique!

Answer (score 0):

Use a sub-query:

```sql
SELECT a, 
       b,
       c,
       CASE 
       WHEN LENGTH(sso_code) > 6
       THEN sso_code
       ELSE 'warning message'
       END AS URL
FROM   (
  SELECT a,
         b,
         c,
         'string' || 
         ( SELECT sso_code 
           FROM   men_sso 
           WHERE  sso_parm LIKE '%IPP_URL_LINK~' || ipp_code || '%' 
           ORDER BY sso_cred, sso_cret 
           FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY ) AS sso_code
  FROM   men_ipp
)
```